# Can't clear a list of related entity beans from an entity bean

Tags: jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0, bidirectional-relation

I'm trying to run the code below, but I keep getting the error "Cannot merge an entity that has been removed".

My DB tables look like this:

```
banner
-id

banner_period
-id
-banner_id
-date
```

My Java code:

```
Banner b = getEntityManager().find(banner.getId());
List<BannerPeriod> bps = b.getBannerPeriodList();
for (BannerPeriod bp : bps) {
    getEntityManager().remove(bp);
}
// <-- removed code that adds periods here
b.setBannerPeriodList(bps);
getEntityManager().merge(b);
```

I can't seem to understand the logic in all this. Could anyone explain what it is, I'm missing here? I've tried to search for answers already, but I find it hard to define keywords that give me relevant results.

UPDATE:

Banner entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bannerId")
private List<BannerPeriod> bannerPeriodList;
```

BannerPeriod entity:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "banner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Banner bannerId;
```

Comment: Looking at the mapping definitions for the Banner / BannerPeriod relationship would help. Can you post them?

Comment: Sure thing. The relation is defined as cascading in the database. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<BannerPeriod> bps` still contains references to `BannerPeriod`s.  So when you call merge on `b` here is what happens.

```
merge on b
-> Cascade all on  bannerPeriodList
-> Iterate over bannerPeriodList and merge them
**ERROR** The values in bannerPeriodList have been removed.
```

Try this

```
bps.clear();
b.setBannerPeriodList(bps);
getEntityManager().merge(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it. What happens is that the list is cleared, but merge doesn't apply the changes to the database. This is strange, because if I clear the list, verify the list is actually empty, add a new BannerPeriod to the list and then merge, the existing periods are still in the database, as is the new one. But when I look at the entities in Java, only the newly added BannerPeriod is in the list. It's not because the relation is broken in the database, because if I restart the server, all periods are back, both the old and new.

Comment: What happens if you omit the merge?  Could you also turn on SQL debugging in your ORM.  It will help see what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks!!! I never even considered doing that. It works when I omit the merge. I found that I must 1) run through the list and do a getEntityManager().remove(BannerPeriod) on each period, then 2) use clear() on the list of periods and finally 3) omit the merge. Only when I do all of those things combined do I avoid exceptions and get the same result both in my entities and my database. Hmm, I'm just thinking right this moment... maybe I have some sort of auto-commit turned on so everything commits twice. I will have to look into that.